# Attacks on MICKEY 2.0 Stream Cipher

Tags: stream-cipher, attack

I would like to know if there are any known attacks, besides from side-channel attacks (differential fault attack, correlation power analysis, template attack), against MICKEY 2.0 or MICKEY-128 2.0.

I already did a deep research on the web using several scientific databases, but I did not found anything besides the above mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there do not seem to be any real attacks beyond those.

Note that MICKEY 2.0 is [part of](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/e2-mickey.html) the eSTREAM portfolio and the one portfolio cipher that was [very successfully attacked](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2008/53500563/53500563.pdf) (pdf), F-FCSR, [was removed](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/portfolio_revision1.pdf) (pdf) quickly thereafter. So you might expect MICKEY to be removed as well if a good enough attack is found.

The [second review](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/ecrypt2/documents/D.SYM.10-v1.pdf) (pdf) of the portfolio from 2012 says:

> It has been noted, e.g. *Gierlichs et al* [[29](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stvl/sasc2008/)], that straightforward implementations of the MICKEY ciphers are likely to be susceptible to timing or power analysis attacks. Otherwise there have been no known cryptanalytic advances against MICKEY 2.0 or MICKEY-128 2.0.